# UIView.animation only running once?

Tags: swift

The following code runs once and it doesn't even animate..it just appears 20 pixels higher. Any idea why? What I want is for the button to move up and down forever.

```
scrollButton.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-20, (self.view.frame.size.height-64)*1-80, 40, 16)
scrollButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ARROW.png"), forState: .Normal)
scrollButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

self.scrollView.addSubview(scrollButton)

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, animations: {
    self.scrollButton.frame.origin.y -= 20
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: in which method is it placed? `viewDidLoad()`? `viewDidAppear(:)`?

Comment: it's in another function that's being called from viewDidLoad

Comment: Did you set up any break points to see what gets executed in what order? or logs? (`print()`)

Comment: What happens if you remove `UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari yep, set up a breakpoint and it hit it during execution.

Comment: @JoeHuang nothing different happened

Comment: are u creating ScrollButton programatically or just setting properties like frame image, tint color ????

Comment: add self.layoutIfNeeded() inside the animation function

Comment: @sohanvanani the button is programatically created

Comment: @JoeHuang that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: then ur code working perfect on my side.  Try to make another demo project with just this animation.

Comment: @sohanvanani then why could the code not be working here?

Comment: have you tried after creating new demo

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old I wanted to add some light to new users.

UIView Animations doesn't work well when called from viewDidLoad try calling it instead from viewWillAppear.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So glad to find this solution, I have spent far too long trying to figure out why in the world my code didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is going to work well , you can make two functions and each one has to move the body and then call the other one . You can use a boolean variable to stop the functions work.